# Why doesn't Java compiler shorten names by default? (both for performance and obfuscation)

Tags: java, compilation, obfuscation

I cannot understand why the Java compiler does not shorten names of variables, parameters, method names, by replacing them with some unique IDs.

For instance, given the class

```
public class VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongClass {

    private int veryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongInt = 3;

    public void veryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongMethod(int veryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongParamName) {
        this.veryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongInt = veryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongParamName;
    }
}
```

the compiled file contains all these very long names:

[image]

Wouldn't simple unique IDs speed the parsing, and also provide a first obfuscation?

Comment: Even private members are available via reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You assume that obfuscation is always desired, but it isn't:

- Reflection would break, and with it JavaBeans and *many* frameworks reliant on it
- Stack traces would become completely unreadable
- If you tried to code against a compiled JAR, you'd end up with code like `String name = p.a1()` instead of `String name = p.getName()`

Obfuscation is normally the very last step taken, when you're delivering the finished app, and even then it's not used particularly often except when the target platform has severe memory constraints.

Comment: True, I didn't think about Reflection, or when it comes to integrate some third-part library.
I was just thinking that it may slightly speed things up.
And regarding the obfuscation you are also right, I would consider it as something that the compiler can do optionally if required.

Comment: It could speed things up a little, I s'pose,  but there are loss-less techniques which work pretty well for most scenarios (like JAR and Pack200 compression). The destructive "compression" you get from obfuscation comes with a high cost, and exactly how you want it to work may vary from case to case, so I'd guess it simply wouldn't carry its own cost to the Java team.

Comment: Couldn't it use a symbol-table instead? And retrieve them on request (eg. at compile-time, reflection, stack-trace)

Comment: @NiklasR Symbol tables would still require the name to *be* there somewhere, and you'd need additional logic for the lazy loading (which comes with it's own costs; thread safety, etc). There's lots of ways to kill a cat, but if you're not even sure you want it dead, why bother? Implementing this feature - which few would benefit from, and they already have 3rd party tools for it - would mean that you'd have to postpone implementing *other* features, and there's a lot of stuff Java sorely needs (like lambdas, VM optimizations which give *significant* performance enhancements, etc).

Answer (score 4):

When you use a class, you refer to its methods by their name. Therefore, the compiler needs to preserve those names.

In any event, I don't see why the compiler should aim to obfuscate anything. Rather, it should aim to do exactly the opposite: be as transparent as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM does use numeric IDs internally.

Class files cannot be obfuscated like that because Java is dynamically linked: names of members must be publicly readable or other classes cannot use your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't simple unique IDs speed the parsing?

No. It would add a mapping that would probably slow it down.

> and also provide a first obfuscation

Yes, but who wants the compiler to do obfuscation buy default? Not me.

Your suggestion has no merit.

Comment: That's why it was not a suggestion, but a question. I'm sure very smart people designed Java, so I was curios to understand why a thing that seemed intuitive to me was not there, and I got the answers.